Dativ Case instead of genitivs case with verbs in german
I know the genitive case can be used to replace a dative that shows possession, e.g. "Der Hund von meinem Freund", "Der Hund meines Freundes".
Often it replaces "von" + dative.
Is it also grammatically correct to do this if it's "part of" a verb and doesn't show posession, e.g. "Ich erzähle von meinem Freund", "Ich erzähle meines Freundes" (Is "Ich erzähle seiner" also correct?)?

As you say, there's the genitive case of possession or affiliation or belonging that you can replace with "von". But there are other uses of genitive, as well as a lot of other uses of "von".
Examples for genitive case not replaceable by von:

Er ist des Einbruchs beschuldigt. => genitive object, not replaceable by von
Sie war die schnellste Läuferin der Schule. => scope, replacing by "von" would sound very colloquial or even silly.

Examples for uses of von not replaceable by genitive:

Wir sind von Berlin nach Dresden gefahren. => local origin, not replaceable
Ihr Deutsch wurde vom Lehrer gelobt. => preposition for the actor in a passive voice sentence, not replaceable.
Ich erzähle von meinem Freund => preposition meaning "about", not replaceable.
Ich bin Klempner von Beruf! => preposition to specify the aspect of a statement, genitive would probably have been possible a few hundred years ago.

Replaceable (possession, belonging):

Wir sind auf den Spuren von Goethe nach Italien gereist. => den Spuren Goethes
Das Auto von Janine => Janines Auto
Der König von England => Englands König


That's basically the conclusion I came to too, but I believe I've read something along the lines of "Er erzählte seiner Erlebnisse" before. As a native speaker this sounds a bit weird or old to me, but not completely wrong.  Also, what about "seiner" in this context; i mean using it as the genitive object.

@Stolas the specific example "Er erzählte seiner Erlebnisse" sounds wrong to me, a bit like an AD&D game master trying to fabricate ancient language. :-) But I can imagine that there are surprising examples where it is possible.

Er erzählte seiner Reise Ablauf (very posh version of "Er erzählt vom Ablauf seiner Reise")

Er erzählte seiner Erlebnisse would replace accusative by genitive which is surely wrong, at least in modern German.

@planetmaker: in your example "Ablauf" is an Akkusativ ("Er erzählte - wen? Die Geschichte, den Ablauf) and "Reise" is a Genitiv depending on "Ablauf", not on "erzählen". It is den Ablauf der Reise.

@HalvarF: "Er ist des Einbruchs beschuldigt" is an "adverbialer Genitiv"; "des Einbruchs is an "Adverbiale" depending on "beschuldigen".

@bakunin: Naja, das scheint mir ein bisschen grammatische Haarspalterei. Ich bin bei sowas ziemlich indifferent, aber ich sehe, dass, wenn man nach "Genitivobjekt" sucht,  "beschuldigen" eines der beliebtesten Beispiele ist. Und man kann doch wohl sagen, dass "beschuldigen" eine Valenz für genau diese Genitivergänzung hat. Ich sehe nicht, was dagegen spricht, das als Objekt zu bezeichnen.

@HalvarF: weil - aber das würde hier den Rahmen sprengen - es keine "Genitivobjekte" gibt. "Objekte" gibt es strenggenommen nur im Akkusativ, das ist der Fall, der für den Gebrauch als Objekt überhaupt erfunden wurde. Der Dativ ist seiner Natur nach ein Adverbiale, der Genitiv ein Bezug: "Peters Auto" -> "das Auto mit Bezug zu Peter" -> "sein Auto". Deshalb kann auch jeder Genitiv durch eine Präposition ersetzt werden - beim Akkusativ geht das nicht, eben weil das der Kasus Obliquus ist. Objekte kann man nicht ersetzen, Bezüge schon.

@bakunin: Auch Begriffe wie "Objekt" kann man natürlich präskriptiv umzudeuten versuchen,, und wenn sich die Linguisten da einig werden, wird das in der nächsten Generation vielleicht auch mal irgendwann in Schulen und dann Köpfen ankommen. Bis dahin könnt Ihr das ja in Eurer Fachsprache so benutzen, aber damit werden andere Definitionen des Begriffes nicht so schnell falsch.

Daß es keine Genitivobjekte geben könne, kommt von Daniel Scholten und ist nicht ernst zu nehmen.

@DavidVogt: eigentlich nicht, aber um im selben Jargon zu antworten: daß es doch welche gibt, kommt von Ihnen und ist auch nicht ernstzunehmen.


Ich erzähle ihr von meinem Freund.
Ich erzähle ihr meines Freundes.

No, because that particular von meinem Freund is a prepositional object to the phrasal verb erzählen von, and not an adverbial of origin.
You can even have both types of item in one phrase:

Ich erzähle ihr vom Hund von meinem Freund.
Ich erzähle ihr vom Hund meines Freundes. (chiefly)

Again, only the adverbial of origin can be replaced by a genitive supplement.


the genitive case can be used to replace a dative that shows possession

Let us first talk about the original role of the Genitiv in indo-european languages: Genitiv marks a relation (a "Bezug"). So, to say:

Peters Auto

we talk about a specific car, the one with a relation to Peter and this relationship is: ownership. The same with:

das Wasser des Meeres

that is not any water but the one (or the sort) found in the sea - with a relationship to the sea.
This is what the Genitiv was made for - express relationships or, rather, relatedness. These relationships could be ownership, being part of one another or some other things.
But if the Genitiv marks a relationship - don't prepositions do the same? Yes, they do! This is why every Genitiv can be replaced by a preposition (and not the other way round) and a preposition showing ownership ("von") commands a Dativ. So, it is the other way round: the preposition replaces the Genitiv (as the marker of a relationship) and then affords the Dativ. Prepositions can never command the Genitiv - this is the case in each and every indo-european language.
(Some might argue that there is "wegen". No, there isn't, but that would be too long to include here, ask a separate question and I will answer.)
There are several functions German uses (and misuses) the Genitiv for and there are lots of (Latin) names for all sort of philological hair-splitting: genitivus explicativus ("eine Frage der Ehre"), genitivus possessivus ("Peters Auto"), genitivus definitivus ("der Begriff der Sünde"), genitivus partitivus ("das Wasser des Meeres"), and so on. But in fact, the Genitiv can mean a relationship to one of these words: noun, adjective, adverb or verb.

adnominaler Genitiv ("Peters Auto", ->noun as subject)
This was the original usage and in e.g. the Hittite language the only one. The oldest known european Genitiv is written in Knossos (Crete), in Linear-B-glyphs and it is one of these:


da pu ri to jo   po ti ni ja
daburintho-jjo   potnia
des Labyrinths   Herrin

(KN Gg 702, Chadwick, 1986, early 14. cent BC, zit. nach Scholten, 2020)

attributiver Genitiv ("ohne Ansehen der Person" ->noun as object)
Nouns are not always subjects but can be objects too. They can also carry attributes and hence they can have relationships expressed by other nouns. Here the "Ansehen" ("regard of", lit. "looking-at") is further qualified: welches Ansehen? Das Ansehen der Person.

adverbialer Genitiv ("sehenden Auges rannte" ->verb)
In contrast to Hittite in Vedic or Ancient Greek (long before Koine) the Genitiv could already relate to a verb, like it can in German from the earliest onset on.



(Sehenden Auges)-> rannte er in sein Verderben.
(Ruhigen Gewissens)-> schlief sie ein.


adverbialer Genitiv ("sehenden Auges" ->verbal attribute)
Not only the verb directly can connect to a Genitiv, also an attribute (aka "adverb") can do so:


Er war bar jeder Hoffnung.
Sie war seiner überdrüssig.


"Ich erzähle meines Freundes"

We are finally in a position to answer your question (and, yes, sorry for the long introduction - I thought I owe you for coming from a linguistical background): yes, that was possible, but only a few centuries ago. Here is Dietmar von Aist in the Codex Manesse, (fol 64, verso):

Es stuont ein frouwe alleine und warte uber heide unde warte ir liebes
Es stand eine Frau allein und wartete über die Heide und wartete ihres Lieblings.

This was part of a free syntactical form which were possible with practically every verb. She waited and at every time this waiting could be further qualfied by a preposition (basically a spatial qualification, because prepositions are always spatial, even if they are chronological. Timely relationships are abstracted spatial relationships.). So, instead of "ihres Lieblings warten" she could have "auf ihren Liebling warten", instead of "des Endes harren" one could "auf das Ende harren ("wait for the end to come" - like you do probably now).
That also worked (and works) with transitive verbs:

Sie klagten ihn des Mordes an.

and with reflexive verbs:

Er rühmte sich großer Taten.

In early medieval times adverbial and adnominal Genitiv could exist alongside, because it was rarely used anyway. Every preposition could follow every verb. Poets at that time made use of that. We see that today only with select few verbs, like "sterben" (to die):

eines natürlichen Todes sterben (Genitiv)
an einer Krankheit sterben
vor Langeweile sterben
durch ein Verbrechen sterben

In the High Middle Age texts the use of Genitive started to become misuse:

Wo bist Du? Des fragte er.

These occasions aren't even that many, but they sound so uncommon to us (and their readers at those times too), non-professional authors imitated it to impress. The adverbial Genitiv would now be used everywhere by lawyers and clerks. This has still retained some momentum until modern times, but ultimately this had to stop. The adverbial Genitiv could only flourish, because the adnominal Genitive was restricted to what it was supposed to do.
But over time the adnominal Genitiv also started to be misused:

Zur Eröffnung der zweiten Saison-Hälfte treffen die ersten beiden der Hinrunden-Tabelle direkt aufeinander
At the opening of the second part of the season the two leaders of the first part meet directly (bundesliga.de)

Notice: two adnominal Genitive in one sentence, but the writer doesn't believe the reader could understand "Hinrundentabelle" or "Saisonhälfte".
Now, suppose we would still have the adverbial Genitive as common as it once was:

Die Journalisten der Yellow Press fragten die Gattin des Sängers der Pläne des Paares.

Wouldn't that be just glorious? Genitivitis in last stage!
The reason why the adverbial Genitiv was more restrictively used after the end of the Middle Age (and waned since) is because the use of the adnominal Genitiv flourished. Many of the prepositions were gone, but not all and once we didn't use the Genitiv there any more the Adverbiale had space to be filled - with prepositions.
Once we did

einer Sache fragen

now we can:

nach einer Sache fragen
um eine Sache fragen

